# Error in CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor.conf"] and USER non-root

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

I need to run docker container always non-root user also under the supervisor.conf all services need to up status but still getting following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/supervisord", line 11, in 
load_entry_point('supervisor==4.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'supervisord')()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/supervisor/supervisord.py", line 358, in main
go(options)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/supervisor/supervisord.py", line 368, in go
d.main()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/supervisor/supervisord.py", line 70, in main
self.options.make_logger()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py", line 1466, in make_logger
loggers.handle_file(
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/supervisor/loggers.py", line 417, in handle_file
handler = RotatingFileHandler(filename, 'a', maxbytes, backups)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/supervisor/loggers.py", line 213, in **init**
FileHandler.**init**(self, filename, mode)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/supervisor/loggers.py", line 160, in **init**
self.stream = open(filename, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/supervisord.log'

My requirement is must login container as a non root user and after docker run will be running all service in supervisor.conf. I need non root user only normal user and don't have any type of access.

Dockerfile last 3 line

RUN useradd -m nonroot && echo "nonroot:nonroot123" | chpasswd

USER nonroot

CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor.conf"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error shows that your supervisord running as a non-privileged user is not allowed to write to a file directly under `/` -> `/supervisord.log`

As per the [supervisord documentation](http://supervisord.org/logging.html#activity-log), the log path defaults to `supervisord.log` in the current working directory, and is configurable via:

> the logfile parameter in the [supervisord] section of the configuration file, defaulting to $CWD/supervisord.log.

You have two options here:

- Change the container's default working directory to a path where your non-root user has full permissions, using the `WORKDIR` Dockerfile command. You should probably do this anyway as you're running it with a non-privileged user
- Edit `/etc/supervisor.conf`, setting a writable path for the log